# FreeNas share showing wrong modified time on MAC

Tags: osx, time, freenas

I have a FreeNas server that we use as a network file share. Nothing fancy. Unfortunately, machines connecting to it report different times for file modification times.

SSHing in and running date gives the correct time:

```
# date
Fri Jun 15 13:21:29 BST 2018
```

**Looking at a particular file:**

On my Linux machine, the time modified is correct: 12:01. Looking on a mac, however, the modified time is 14:01.

The correct time is 12:01 which is what `ls -lh` gives.

**EDIT:**

All machines are set to London Europe timezone and have NTP enabled.

Comment: It would have helpde if you'd shown the output of `ls -l` from the Mac (did you check the timezones? ls always shows the time relative to the users timezone / filesystem data is stored in GMT)

Comment: @symcbean  Sorry, I am not a mac guy. How can I `ls -l` the server files from the mac? Obviously I could SSH in but then I would be running the command directly on the server which is what I have already done

Comment: Try the terminal tool in the applications folder.